# Splitting a vector into vector of vectors based on key

Tags: vector, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I have a single vector of objects that I would like to transform into a vector of vectors of objects, where each object in the sub-vectors have the same value for a specific member. e.g.

```
[{:sku "105"}, {:sku "105"}, {:sku "120"}]
```

becomes

```
[[{:sku "105"}, {:sku "105"}], [{:sku "120"}]]
```

I'm trying to grasp the functional way of thinking, but I'm pretty sure I'm not there yet, as my code seems pretty unwieldy. But here's what I have so far:

```
(defn separate-by-invoice [original-invoices]
  (let [sorted-invoices (sort-by :invoice-number original-invoices)]
    (def temp-invoices [])
    (reduce (fn [final-invoices invoice]
      (let [prev-invoice-number (get-in (last temp-invoices) [:invoice-number])
            invoice-number (get-in invoice [:invoice-number])]
        (if (= prev-invoice-number invoice-number)
          (do
            (into temp-invoices invoice))
          (do
            (into final-invoices temp-invoices)
            (def temp-invoices [])
            (into temp-invoices invoice))))
        final-invoices)
      []
      sorted-invoices)))
```

Basically, my thinking is, I form a vector, temp-invoices, and fill it with all of the entries with the same invoice number, and then once we've gotten all of them, insert that vector into final-vector, and return that value. But instead it seems final-invoices is always an empty vector. What am I doing wrong? How is this typically done in clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lets break this into two sub-questions:

```
user> (def x [{:sku "105"}, {:sku "105"}, {:sku "120"}])
#<Var@18bc9d90: [{:sku "105"} {:sku "105"} {:sku "120"}]>
```

first group the like data together:

```
user> (sort-by :sku x)
({:sku "105"} {:sku "105"} {:sku "120"})
```

Then split it on each change:

```
user> (partition-by :sku (sort-by :sku x))
(({:sku "105"} {:sku "105"}) ({:sku "120"}))
```

which can also be written using the threaded style to make the flow easier to read:

```
user> (->> x
           (sort-by :sku)
           (partition-by :sku)
           (mapv vec))
[[{:sku "105"} {:sku "105"}] [{:sku "120"}]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's so much easier than I thought.

Answer (score 3):

You may use combination of [`group-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) and [`mapv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) (in case you want to get vector as a result):

```
(def data [{:sku "105"}, {:sku "105"}, {:sku "120"}])
(group-by :sku data) 
;; => {"105" [{:sku "105"} {:sku "105"}], "120" [{:sku "120"}]}

(mapv second (group-by :sku data))
;; => [[{:sku "105"} {:sku "105"}] [{:sku "120"}]]
```

Optionally use [threading](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) for better readability:

```
(->> data
  (group-by :sku)
  (mapv second))
```

Comment: Instead of `(mapv second)` I would suggest to just use the `vals` function to extract all of the values from the map.

Comment: good point. but you need additionally wrap it with `vec` in case you need exactly vector (and no other seq) as a result

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `group-by` function:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core 
        clojure.test 
        tupelo.core))

(def input    [ {:id 1 :sku 105} 
                {:id 2 :sku 105}
                {:id 3 :sku 120} ] )

(def result   [ [ {:id 1 :sku 105} 
                  {:id 2 :sku 105} ]
                [ {:id 3 :sku 120} ] ] )

(deftest t-separate-by-sku
  ; the result of 'group-by' is a map keyed by the grouping value 
  ; (the sku in this case)
  (is (= (group-by :sku input)
         { 105 [{:id 1, :sku 105} {:id 2, :sku 105}],  
           120 [{:id 3, :sku 120}] } ))
  ; we do not care about the grouping value, so just extract
  ; the values from the map with 'vals'
  (is (= (vals (group-by :sku input))   
         result)))
```